# How to call pg_test_timing in Ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql

The `pg_test_timing` command is cited as [relevant caveat](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/using-explain.html#USING-EXPLAIN-CAVEATS)  and have [some documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgtesttiming.html)... But documentaion not say how to call it.

```
root@machine:~# pg_test_timing
pg_test_timing: command not found
```

Why PostgreSQL official distribution not offers it automatically?

### dump locate

```
locate pg_test_timing
/etc/alternatives/pg_test_timing.1.gz
/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_test_timing
/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/pg_test_timing-10.mo
/usr/share/locale/es/LC_MESSAGES/pg_test_timing-10.mo
/usr/share/locale/fr/LC_MESSAGES/pg_test_timing-10.mo
/usr/share/locale/ko/LC_MESSAGES/pg_test_timing-10.mo
/usr/share/locale/pl/LC_MESSAGES/pg_test_timing-10.mo
/usr/share/locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/pg_test_timing-10.mo
/usr/share/locale/sv/LC_MESSAGES/pg_test_timing-10.mo
/usr/share/man/man1/pg_test_timing.1.gz
/usr/share/postgresql/10/man/man1/pg_test_timing.1.gz
```

Comment: It is right here /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_test_timing

Comment: Hi @IvanMogila, yes I do `chmod 777` and  the run big path... But what is wrong with the official distribution?  Why it is not a real command like dbcreate or any other "rare use command" that stay there as the documentation say?

Comment: You can create a link for pg_test_timing in /usr/bin if you want to use it without full path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a quote nn "Getting Started" section of docs:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tutorial-createdb.html

> If you see a message similar to:
>
> `createdb: command not found`
>
> then PostgreSQL was not installed
>   properly. Either it was not installed at all or your shell's search
>   path was not set to include it. Try calling the command with an
>   absolute path instead:
>
> `$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb mydb`

(formatting mine)

Please use this advise against other binaries as well.

Either add `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/` to your `$PATH` or use the full path to binaries folder...

Also, please note, this is rather not a problem of "PostgresSQL official distribution", but rather a installer you use for the distribution of Linux you are on...

also it is mentioned in docs if you build it from source *which would be more suitable for the title of official distribution):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/install-post.html

> If you installed into /usr/local/pgsql or some other location that is
>   not searched for programs by default, you should add
>   /usr/local/pgsql/bin (or whatever you set --bindir to in Step 1) into
>   your PATH.

Comment: Hi @VaoTsun, thanks!  I see Debian distribution (eg. `apt` command at UBUNTU LTS) as the most popular, so there are some responsibility of PostgreSQL... If you have some contact with PostgreSQL team, can you show this little "distribution bug" to them?